# How can a website display dynamic values allowing users to calculate on each of its page refresh

Tags: jsp

I have a website which accepts comments from a user .
for example see this figure here a sample demo

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/capturezyd.jpg/

Here before allowing a comment from a user he needs to do a simple calculation ( 2+3 as shown in above figure ) , this is to make sure that the user is a Human being .
Now these numbers are not static , they would change for every refresh of the page .

Please tell me how to dynamically provide numbers in the UI , so that the calculation part is dynamic ??

Answer (score 0):

Is `2+3` a static text (bad idea, trivial to read and compute by bot) or an image? Anyway, here is the simplest way:

1. When rendering a page randomize two terms (`2` and `3` in this example).
2. Place these terms in the session.
3. Render terms on the page if static text used. | If using an image, create a second servlet `/image`.
4. When user submits a form, compare the value with a sum of terms loaded from the session.

Ad. 3. When using an image, `/image` servlet should return an image with `2+3` representation. This servlet should use the terms saved in the session seconds earlier. This servlet will be accessed immediately after loading the form JSP page.

Comment: Is 2+3 a static text ?? No this is dynamic for every page refresh .

Comment: I know it is different for every page (see point 1.) What I meant was: is it rendered within page HTML as text or served as a separate `<img/>`? Nevertheless my recipe works for both cases.